# Restoring a .tar.gz file that was split using split command and joined using cat command

Tags: split, backup, tar, restore, cat

I had a backup of my home directory stored in a .tar.gz file using

`tar -cvzf backup.tar.gz ~`

I had then split this file into 151 files using

`split -b 3584M -d backup.tar.gz part_`

For restoring the backup, I did

`cat -v part_* > backup.tar.gz`

followed by

`tar xvzf backup.tar.gz`

Now, this is where my issue starts.

The 151 *part* files have a total size of 564.2 GB. So, the cat output file size should be the same. But, the cat output file size is 1.3 TB!. This is where the process is most likely messing up.

Additionally, upon entering the `tar` command to uncompress the archive, I get an error saying

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

On checking the file with

`file backup.tar.gz`

I get

`backup.tar.gz: ASCII text, with very long lines`

I could not find a reason as to why the file is an ASCII text file as opposed to a compressed tar archive.
I'm stumped! This is my only backup, contains months of my work, and I desperately need it to work.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: I suggest to remove `-v` (show nonprinting) from `cat` command.

Comment: Thanks @Cyrus! Trying it out. Will update the comment after it's done.